# Rewrite magento catalog search url using xml

Tags: magento-1.7, catalog, catalogsearch, url-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule for catalogsearch to rewrite url from :

> localhost/magento/catalogsearch/result/?q=product

TO:

> localhost/magento/?q=product

How to write rewrite in xml please help me.

Comment: You need to only rewrite the url to somehow point to it or do you want also to point your search engine form action to that url? Option 1 is possible, option 2 is a lot of work.

Comment: If you find an answer, add it here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303097/how-to-change-magento-search-url-result

Comment: @mbalparda ..I want to go for option 1. where it somehow point to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native rewrite feature via config.xml as follow

```
<global>
<rewrite>
    <designer_url>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/author/id/#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[/designer/index/index/id/]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </designer_url>
</rewrite>
</global>
```

First node  is the rewrited URL and  is the original URL.

Comment: I have tried this rule but not working for my catalog search url.. It's not affecting to url.. can you help me to write this rule for catalog search url..